# Dock (Docky) disappears when I put my computer to sleep

Tags: unity, suspend, docky

My dock disappears when I put the computer to sleep. It's there when I go to sleep, but gone when I wake it up. I can easily start the dock again by using unity search and searching for "docky" and clicking the icon. The app then starts again. But I don't want to have to do this every time! It's annoying.

Pardon my English, I am Italian.

Computer specs:

Make: Lenovo
Model: ThinkPad R61
Features: Bluetooth, WiFi, ThinkLight, etc.
Reply with answers/any questions.

Comment: Cairo Dock is considerably more stable than Docky. It is better integrated with ubuntu (even offering a standalone option).

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed (at least for me) by updating Docky to version 2.2.1, which at the time of writing this answer, was in the testing stage (it can crash some other ways), so you have to add a PPA containing it.

Run following commands in console:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --yes dist-upgrade`